# How to save a particular, mutable "order" into a database

Tags: database, sorting, database-design

Suppose I have some objects, and I want the user to be able to reorder them in any way they wish, say, by dragging them around. So I'd have

- Cheese
- Muffins
- Milk

And then the user drags 'milk' to the top, making the new order

- Milk
- Cheese
- Muffins

Is there a best practice how to store the order of these objects in a database? The naive approach would probably be to just store a numerical value called "order" for each object, but this seems like too much hassle to me, because you'd have to shuffle the order-values around most of the time.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495390/orm-or-something-to-handle-sql-tables-with-an-order-column-efficiently

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ORM or something to handle SQL tables with an order column efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495390/orm-or-something-to-handle-sql-tables-with-an-order-column-efficiently)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The "naive" approach you suggest is also the best practice!

Comment: Would the order column be indexed?

Comment: @Ryker not necessarily, but quite possibly - perhaps along with another column(s).  It depends on whether this gives any performance benefit.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! I'll see if I can figure out if indexing the order column has a tangible performance boost

Answer (score 29):

The best way I've found to handle this is to have a floating point order field. When you move something between two other items, set that field to halfway between its neighbors.

This is cheap on both reads and writes. The only downside is the floats keep getting longer :)

Comment: +1 for floating point data type. If you set initial order values to be offset by 100 and used floats, you could avoid gigantic decimal places and still have the benefit of never needing to adjust a data type of search for a collision.

Answer (score 15):

Taking Tony Andrews' answer into consideration, you could alternatively store a "next" index with each entry.  Then when you pull them all in, walk the array by following the chain.  That makes moving an item easier, as you only have to touch maximum two rows.

The disadvantage with this approach is if you ever need a subset (e.g. the first 3 items) you still need to pull in all the items, or use a SQL loop.  So it's between affecting all rows during update, or accessing all items during read.  As ever, measure the speed and see which is better for your situation.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at Tony Andrew's and Mark's answers in particular, it seems I really have only two alternatives:

- Saving a 'next' value, making the objects behave like a linked list (see Mark's answer)
  With this, changing the order is cheap, but I'd have to retrieve the items and *then* sort them by their 'next' value, which is expensive
- Saving an 'order' value (see Tony Andrew's answer)
  This makes retrieving cheap but saving a new order potentially expensive, because in the worst case, I'd have to change all the order values. cletus points out that one could use a large number in the form of 2^n for the order multiplier.

*Meta:* All of these answers are good and correct, which one should I choose as correct?

Comment: Since you asked about storing in a DB, I'd vote for the "naive" approach .. by originally inserting the objects with an offset of, say 100, you could minimize the re-order collision (when you'd have to change more than one object to re-insert in a new position)

Comment: Neither is absolutely 100% "best".  If you have way more reads than writes, retrieval speed is probably the primary concern.  If you have a lot of writes or have to order a large number of items, write speed is important instead.  It's a case-by-case judgement.

Answer (score 5):

In my applications read operations are going to happen much more frequently than writes. Go with the numerical value to indicate sort order and deal with the cost of reordering the items. This is more than made up for by the fact that you can efficiently retrieve the items in the correct order for display purposes (which in a typical application happens more frequently than resorting does).

Also, as already mentioned, if you retrieve a subset of the data (filter on type or something) the remaining items are still in the proper sort order.

Remember the mantra K.I.S.S.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have them redisplayed in the same order AND you want them to be able to reordered at any time I don't think you can get away from storing some value that indicates display priority in the database.  I've used the very approach you describe to order items in an FAQ, researchers associated with a grant, the order of items in a menu, ...

Answer (score 2):

If the amount of data is small, I choose to create a sort table.

When reading, the data and sorting information are handed over to the client, and the client handles it by itself.

like:

### SortTable

| UserId | OrderId | SortIds(json) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 34 | 2146 | [32,34,54,2,56] |
| 1 | 26 | [2,54,14,19,156] |

Answer (score 1):

Yup, in a relational database there is no order, it's one of the fundamental concepts. So there's just no way without a numerical value or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can user previous Id, every new insertion you set last inserted row ID as previous ID like this,

```css
table, td {
  border: .2px solid black
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>PREV_ID</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>first_item</td>
    <td><i>&lt;null&gt;</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>second_item</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>thid_item</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

any time you reordering easily insert with last row id, 
If you use next id every new insertion you need to update previous one, 
If you use sort order in any update you have to update multiple rows.
Now postgreSQL recursive query available for selecting

Comment: The question is tagged as `database` and `database-design` and you are explaining some html table stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you could use an [Order Statistic Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree) if you want to get a specific element at a value, or just some kind of **B-Tree** in general to store the values. If they change, you are changing `O(log n)` items in the worst case. If you have 30,000 items, you only need to change 4 or 5 or them to keep the order.