# What is the most efficient way to store a sort-order on a group of records in a database?

Tags: mysql, algorithm, database-design, performance

Assume PHP/MYSQL but I don't necessarily need actual code, I'm just interested in the theory behind it.

A good use-case would be Facebook's photo gallery page. You can drag and drop a photo on the page, which fires an Ajax event to save the new sort order. I'm implementing something very similar.

For example, I have a database table "photos" with about a million records:

**photos**
id : int,
userid : int,
albumid : int,
sortorder : int,
filename : varchar,
title : varchar

Let's say I have an album with 100 photos. I drag/drop a photo into a new location and the Ajax event fires off to save on the server.

Should I be passing the entire array of photo ids back to the server and updating every record? Assume input validation by "`WHERE userid`=`loggedin_id`", so malicious users can only mess with the sort order of their own photos

Should I be passing the photo id, its previous sortorder index and its new sortorder index, retrieve all records between these 2 indices, sort them, then update their orders?

What happens if there are thousands of photos in a single gallery and the sort order is changed?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What about just using an `integer` column which defines the order? By default you assign numbers * 1000, like 1000, 2000, 3000.... and if you move 3000 between 1000 and 2000 you change it to 1500. So in most cases you don't need to update the other numbers at all. I use this approach and it works well. You could also use `double` but then you don't have control about the precision and rounding errors, so rather don't use it.

**So the algorithm would look like**: say you move B to position after A. First perform select to see the order of the record next to A. If it is at least +2 higher than the order of A then you just set order of B to fit in between. But if it's just +1 higher (there is no space after A), you select the bordering records of B to see how much space is on this side, divide by 2 and then add this value to the order of all the records between A and B. That's it!

(Note that you should use transaction/locking for any algorithm which contains more than a single query, so this applies to this case too. The easiest way is to use InnoDB transaction.)

Comment: Isn't it the algorithm used by Typo3? IMO this is very expensive because you still need to lookup many numbers and also you need to provide a Gui to change the sort order in big number.

Comment: Can you explain, why you downvoted my answer? Your comment is absolutely out. The algorithm I provided is better than anything what has been proposed here until now!

Comment: IMO there is a better algorithm then assign numbers. I use the timestamp of the creation of the file and then just swap this timestamp to sort.

Comment: By the way, it is much more useful than linked lists. How would you do ordered select efficiently with linked lists? Anyway, you are downvoting for no reason at all!

Comment: Tomas: If you want to start a fight... I give you explanation: Typo3 is using this, it's very much code and I presented you my solution.

Comment: 'Then just swap this timestamp to sort'??? Man, if you haven't noticed, this discussion is not about swapping, but about reinserting, which is completely different thing. Moving image in gallery to another position is not swapping. Swapping is of course trivial, but reinserting is a different thing.

Comment: @Jitamaro let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1772/discussion-between-tomas-telensky-and-epitaph)

Comment: I don't care about what Typo3 is using, my algorithm is just quite trivial improvement what had been asked.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to move the discussion to chat, I just clicked the wrong button.

Comment: @TomasTelensky I like this idea very much. Now what happens when 2 records' sortorders converge? Not that this is ever likely to happen, but what would you do in this case? Thanks!

Comment: in that case you would do what you proposed in your question, i.e. move all the records between these 2 records (add some number to the order of all these records). You now you can safely add 1, because there is at least one free 'space', but it would be better to find out how the space is big and add a half of it - this is more clever, because you are less likely to need that operation again in the future.

Comment: That makes sense.ut as far as the insertion, you'd have to perform a SELECT query for the 2 bordering records, split the difference, then UPDATE the

Comment: (Ignore that last comment) That makes sense. Now as far as the re-insertion algorithm --- You would pass back the photo id and the new index, perform a SELECT query for the 2 bordering records, split the difference, then UPDATE the record with the split index. Am I missing anything?

Comment: I'm a fan of using integers for determining row order.

Comment: @swese44: exactly. But you have to test if there is still free space for the new order index. Let's say you move B to position after A, so if there is no space after A then select the bordering records of B to see how much space is on this side, divide by 2 and then add this value to the order of all the records between A and B.

Comment: I've added this alg. description to the answer.

Comment: Regardless of which algorithm you're using, *at some point* you will have to determine if you have space for a new order anyway. Timestamps/dates have a finite accuracy, it is nothing more than the integer solution proposed here just with more digits. You could just as easily argue that instead of 1000, 2000, 3000, you use 1000000, 2000000, 3000000. You're just postponing the "problem" here. In any case, please take this to chat. Comments are for comments to improve/fix problems with the answer, not to work out which solution is best/good/acceptable.

Comment: I solved this problem in similar manner and also answered someone else here - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/206699/35849

Comment: @TMS I know this is an old issue, but just wondered if you happen to know what kind of algorithm this is named? Is there anything on Wiki I can lookup to see an example code of the algorithm? Having trouble wracking my head around it, though I understand the basic concept.

Answer (score 6):

Store as a linked list, sortorder is a foreign key reference to the next photo_id in the set.

Comment: That would be useful for UPDATE, but does it provide for an efficient SELECT with ORDER BY?

Comment: @swese: A select would be a collection of joins minus one of your LIMIT http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151286/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-the-order-between-rows-in-the-database

Comment: @swese44 Order the results in memory, since you'll be fetching the complete result set to show it to the user anyway.

Comment: But that's not so good if you are showing paginated results, say 20 at a time, if there are thousands of photo records for one gallery. You'd have to fetch thousands of records from the db, sort them in memory, then only display 20 of them. Really doesn't seem too efficient, at least in this situation.

Comment: I've yet to see a gallery with thousands of photos in it - that seems pretty useless from an organizational point of view. I can't imagine what a UI to let you rearrange images in a gallery that big would have to look like.

Comment: @Nick I would not want to put a limit on the number of photos a user could upload. Regardless of of how dumb most users are, limiting uploads could be very frustrating for a small percentage of users. Pagination is not a new concept. Either way, I think we'll implement Tomas's solution.

Comment: @swese44 Limiting the number of photos they can put in an album is different from limiting the number of photos they can upload full-stop. And any limit could be large enough users are unlikely to reach it - 5000 is reasonable. The point I was making, though, is that there's no point considering arbitrarily large limits if you don't have the UI to support it.

Answer (score 1):

this would probably be a 'linked list' construct.

Answer (score 0):

To me the second method of updating is the way to go (update only the range that changes). You are mentioning "What happens if there are thousands of photos in a single gallery ...", and to me that is never going to happen. Lets take your facebook example. Facebook doesn't show thousands of photos on one page, they split it up to about 10-20 per page.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do this in a nonrelational database is to store a list of photo IDs on the 'album' entity/record, in the order desired. Reordering the photos results in reordering the list, and only a single database write.

Some SQL databases (Eg, PostgreSQL) have native list datatypes, but MySQL doesn't. You could serialize the list as a string or binary on MySQL.

3rd-normal-form trained database gurus will scream at you that this is a terrible approach, but RDBMSes are optimized for OLAP type queries, where query flexibility is more important than read performance. Webapps are best written with a 'write heavy, read light' strategy in mind, and this sort of denormalization is exactly in line with that.

Comment: Ya, but this is a "ready heavy, write light" situation. 99% of all hits will be read, the number of re-sorting "write" hits would be very low compared to users and spiders just browsing pages. If it takes an extra query every single time a gallery page is loaded to get the order of photo records before you can query for the actual photo records with a paginated offset, I'm not sure if the tradeoff is worth it.

Comment: @swese44 But it doesn't take an extra query - you're already loading the gallery record.