# Best way to store sort order/priority?

Tags: mysql, sorting

I'm using MySQL. I have a table where I need to be able to sort manually set the priority/order of the rows. I had originally thought of assigning each row an arbitrary order (1, 2, 3, etc.), then just "swapping" the order with the row being moved, but I don't think this is the best way to do it.

After doing some reading at related questions on here ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804166/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-store-a-sort-order-on-a-group-of-records-in-a)), a lot of people have said to assign a value to the priority column based off the id column (id * 1000). And to rearrange the rows, you would divide/subtract the difference between the columns. I don't quite understand how this works.

This is the layout of the table I need to sort.

```
CREATE TABLE liability_detail (
   id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   analysis_id int NOT NULL, //(many-to-one relationship with analysis table)
   other_columns various datatypes
   sequence int DEFAULT 0
)
```

I'd like to setup an easy way to manage the priority of rows so I can easily sort them without having to write a lot of code to manage everything.

Comment: I believe with a little more detail it would be possible to answer this without such tricks as a "priority" columns which gets swapped or updated. Can you lay out the formula for priority calculation? What is the reasoning behind "moving rows"? I suspect a proper `ORDER BY` might be possible to produce

Comment: Consider the linked list approach. This avoids having to update all other rows when moving a row up or down in the list. With a linked list, you only have to update at most three rows (that includes the one you're moving). Of course, it's hard to query against it, so you'd probably implement the order only in code.

Comment: This application performs financial analyses on our customers. Our users need to be able to prioritize some finances by moving them to the top, and moving lower priority finances to the bottom. This process is manual because there are just too many factors to perform an automatic sort using ORDER BY. Sometimes users need to move a row from the middle to the top, and sometimes the second row to the bottom.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to store a sort-order on a group of records in a database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804166/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-store-a-sort-order-on-a-group-of-records-in-a)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up following the advice in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6804302/731052

I set the sort-order column = id * 1000 so I could get unique orders. So far this works very well and haven't had any problems with it.