# Most efficient way to store arbitrary sort order?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, sorting

I am currently working on an Android app where users can order their list via drag and drop in any order they want. Therefore, I must store the sort order in a variable in a column. I was thinking of giving each row a number like 100000, 200000, 300000, etc and if a user moves an item between 100000 and 200000, then its sort number becomes the average of its neighbours ie 150000. This way, I only have to update the single row's sort number as opposed to every row in the table if I did a normal i+1 sort value.

What is the most efficient? Do large numbers use more resources or take longer to sort? I only expect <100 rows so if large numbers take longer to sort, I might be better off using smaller numbers and "resetting" more often (when two sort numbers converge onto each other). I know with so few rows, it wouldn't really matter if I just did a i+1 sort method and update every row in my db every time. But I am also syncing my SQLite data with a BAAS and most of them do not allow batch saving. So for every row I modify, I have to make 1 API request. That is why I am trying to minimize the amount of rows I modify when I reorder an item.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know enough about it to write a complete answer, but my guess is that you would want to simulate a linked list in your db.  Have the list item hold values for the id's of a previous and next list item.  http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list

Comment: The data may be synced between multiple users/devices so id rather not rely on other objects that may exist locally but are actually already deleted on the server.

Comment: At 100 rows nothing you do will make any appreciable difference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to store a sort-order on a group of records in a database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804166/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-store-a-sort-order-on-a-group-of-records-in-a)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547022/how-do-i-store-orders

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using my original method of giving each row a number like 100000, 200000, 300000, etc and if a user moves an item between 100000 and 200000, then its sort number becomes the average of its neighbours ie 150000. Since the number of rows I have is relatively small ~50, I opted for this method which may not be the efficient but is the simplest.

Comment: I had a great answer for you but everyone flamed me cuz it wasn't a "linked list".   Bunch of technocrats on this site, always getting hung on the deets

Comment: Move the second list item to the first place. Repeat that 18 times and you will get in troubles. [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd762/1)